# Word 2007: How to set "Show recommended styles" on open

Tags: vba

I'm trying to force Word to show only the styles a group of people are going to work with. The following macro shows only the styles I want. But this only works if "Recommended" has been selected in the "Select styles to show" drop-down list from the Style Pane Options dialog box.

Is there a way to set this in vba so that when opening the document the user only sees the chosen styles?

Thanks,

D

---

> Public Sub StyleSet()
>
> ```
> ' First, turn off all Style visibility:
> ```
>
> For Each mystyle In ActiveDocument.Styles
>          mystyle.Visibility = True
>      Next mystyle
>
> ```
> 'update the styles
> ```
>
> ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles
>
> ```
> ' Then, turn on the ones you want to see:
> ```
>
> ActiveDocument.Styles("Click").Visibility = False
>      ActiveDocument.Styles("Button").Visibility = False
>       ActiveDocument.Styles("Caption").Visibility = False
>
> ```
> 'update the styles again
> ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles
> ```
>
> End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Do you want ... ?

```
ActiveDocument.FormattingShowFilter = wdShowFilterFormattingRecommended
ActiveDocument.StyleSortMethod = wdStyleSortRecommended
```